# C# FTP Uload Acces denied Error 550

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

My Class FTP work fine wtih my FTP server, but not with my client FTP server.

```
public class UploadToFTP
    {
        public void UploadFTP(string LeSource, string Desti, string CodeClient)
        {
           Pers_Conf oConf =  LeConf.Get_Config(CodeClient);


         // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
           FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + oConf.FtpServer + oConf.FtpChemin +"/" + Desti);

            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(oConf.FtpLogin, oConf.FtpPwd);



            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.UsePassive = true;


            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(LeSource);
            byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;


            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            //Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();
        }
    }
```

this line is not work : Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

Anybody have solution ?
i have change the right into 777.

Thanks you in advance,
Stev

Comment: Are you sure that you have the proper Network Credentials setup for the Client.. perhpas it's the Anonymous login that's causing the problem shouldn't you have a user name / password setup for that FTP site..?

Comment: No i am not sure. how can i use the right  Network Credentials setup for the Client ?

Comment: you need to have a Account Name / Password setup on the FTP server.. and pass those Credentials.. if it's working on the Server but not on the Client.. that's usually a Right's / permissions issue or however they setup the FTP on the server end.. is there someone there whom you can ask or talk to, to get the proper information...?

Answer (score 1):

[The Solutions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/8caa2570-f185-4c31-91b3-940ab7c7c3a2)

/ work only several ftp servers, but //  it works perfectly everywhere